# Why does my first input run through the do while even thought the input is 0

Tags: java

I am doing a school program about Casino App. First of all it is alright, but then I find out that something goes wrong with my first input. It is weird that only the first input goes wrong, others are fine. I am wondering what causes that happen and why?

```
public class test1
{   

public static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int winnings;
    int bet = getBet();

    do
    {   
    TripleString thePull = pull();
    getPayMultiplier(thePull);
    winnings = bet * getPayMultiplier(thePull);
    display(thePull, winnings);
    bet =getBet();
    }

    while(bet != 0);
        System.out.print("Thank you!");
}





public static int getBet()
{
    final double MAX_BET = 50;
    final double MIN_BET = 0 ;
    String prompt, userResponse;
    int Response;

    do
    {
        prompt = "How much would you like to bet (1 - 50) or 0 to quit?";
        System.out.print(prompt);
        userResponse = input.nextLine();
        Response = Integer.parseInt(userResponse);
    }
    while (Response < MIN_BET || Response > MAX_BET);

    return Response;
}
```

My question is that when I put the first input as 0 (bet !=0 ) it shows :

```
How much would you like to bet (1 - 50) or 0 to 
quit? 0
whirrrrrr .... and your pull is ...
BAR BAR BAR
Sorry, you lose.

How much would you like to bet (1 - 50) or 0 to 
quit?
```

which is wrong. it should quit immediately, but if I put 0 anywhere except the first input, it works:

```
How much would you like to bet (1 - 50) or 0 to 

quit? 1
whirrrrrr .... and your pull is ...
7 BAR cherries
Sorry, you lose.

How much would you like to bet (1 - 50) or 0 to quit? 0
Thanks for coming to Casino Loceff
```

Why is that?

Comment: Read about do while statements. Also read about while statements. But basically do while statements execute the loop once before checking the condition. Check this image -> https://me.me/i/while-not-edge-do-run-run-while-not-edge-5b875ee64adb4e939ee50ad394309509

Comment: What are you expecting to see?  Your bet of 0 is not less than 0, so the while loop terminates normally.

Answer (score 0):

Because `do-while` loop will run through the loop at least once and check the breaking condition only at the end. If you don’t want that behavior swap it for a normal while loop.

```
while(condition) { // your statements }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Response is 0.  And that is not less than MIN_BET (which is 0), so the loop doesn't repeat.

Change it to <= MIN_BET, or (probably better), change MIN_BET to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the usage of a `do-while` loop.  The purpose of a do-while is to ensure the code block will *always execute at least once*.

The difference between a regular `while` and a `do-while` is when the expression is evaluated.

In a regular `while` loop the expression is checked before each loop starts.  "Should I run the code?".  This means that if the expression is false it will never run the block even once.

Whereas with a `do-while` the expression is checked *after* the code block executes - "Should I do this again?".  So even if the expression is false the code block will be executed the first time.

Try using a regular `while` loop instead of `do-while`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely here

```
public static int getBet()
{
    final double MAX_BET = 50;
    final double MIN_BET = 1;//this should be 1 since you're asking for users to enter 1-50
    String prompt, userResponse;
    int Response;

    do
    {
        prompt = "How much would you like to bet (1 - 50) or 0 to quit?";
        System.out.print(prompt);
        userResponse = input.nextLine();
        Response = Integer.parseInt(userResponse);

        //simplest way is just to add a condition here with an if statement to break the loop if the user enters 0
       if(userResponse == 0){
           break;
       }

    }
    while (Response >= MIN_BET && Response <= MAX_BET);

    return Response;
    }
```